# Break a function SendSMSMessage when application onDestroy

Tags: java, android

I have a function: `protected void sendSMSMessage()...` that automatically sends a message when a countdowntimer reaches 0.
What I want to do is break the function to not send the message when I click in the back button.
What should go in my `onDestroy`?

```
protected void onDestroy()
    {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (tts != null) { //tts= texttospeech (don't matter)
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.stop(); //mp=mediaplayer (don't matter)

    }
```

This is my function:

```
protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");
        /*
        String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
        */
        String phoneNo = "000000000";
        String message = "Teste";

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So I want to stop the function of sending sms when I click backbutton.

Any advice?

Comment: Please ask your question more clear way. we don't know what are tts,mp...And if you want to react on back button i suggest you to use onBackPressed callback method.

Comment: What does your sendSMSMessage() and countdown look like?

Comment: You need to show some more code of urs..

Comment: override the back button to cancel your timer. <  Note non of the code I mention is shown above